Why don't the Beta Israel accept the Talmud?
According to a Chacham I discussed this with: While some members of Beta Israel community subscribe to Rabbinic Judaism including Falash Mura who left Christianity, they do not practice it fully. The majority of the community subscribes and practices the pre-Talmudic Jewish Haymanot.
Accordingly, why don't the Beta Israel accept the Talmud?

How do you know they don't?

Why should they?

I asked a chacham @Harel13.

Sure ... the Chacham's statement was about the Beta Ezrael as a community. Obviously individuals will do what they will just as large swathes of "Rabbinical Jews" are not orthopraxic.

The question is "Why don't the Beta Israel accept the Talmud?"  My answer is: "Because they never knew what it is in the first place."  (And, like us, they are reluctant to change age-old traditions.)

They didn’t reject it. They’re not Karaim. Rabbi Hadane and other leaders follow the Shulchan Aruch

How is this guy not banned yet?

@הראל Haymanot are not pre-Talmudic. It is post-Talmudic. The practices of the Beta Israel community are relatively recent. Because of Christian persecution, all religious books outside of the Christian translation of the OT into Ge'ez were outlawed for centuries before the Beta Israel regained contact with the rest of the Jewish nation. Whatever additional Torah writings they had, were lost. They developed Haymanot in their absence.

Were these texts lost when the Beta Israel King destroyed the Library to prevent it from falling into the mishrikist emperor's hands? @conceptualinertia

My understanding is that most of the Beta Israel that immigrated to Israel underwent גיור לחומרא - conversion of stringency (see Jews in Israel: Contemporary Social and Cultural Patterns, p. 131 regarding some of the controversy surrounding it). Any Orthodox conversion requires that a candidate of conversion accept the authority of rabbinic Judaism (Bekhoroth 30b, H. Issurei Biah 14:8), which in turn means acceptance of the Talmud.
The statement attributed to the anonymous Hakham makes it sound like the Beta-Israel actively reject the Talmud. I am unaware of any member of their community that vocally expresses such a perspective.
Just like may other 'olim from around the world, the Beta-Israel face pressure to assimilate to Israeli culture. This particular pressure may be more acutely felt by members of the Beta-Israel due to racial differences (see Ethiopian Jews in Israel: A Part of the People or Apart From the People? Steven Kaplan, Hagar Salamon). Given that Israeli-culture is generically secular leaning, this may culminate in lax observance of halakhah. This is not necessarily a conscious and active rejection of halakhah but rather simply a sliding into what is "comfortable" given the societal pressures.
Place this tendency in conjunction with the fact that this community has had its own traditions for at least a few hundred years (see The Beta Israel Falasha in Ethiopia: From Earliest Times to the Twentieth Century, ch. 3), it is natural that if/when there is a religious impulse by such individuals it would be expressed in their ancestral way (alongside any other widely practiced Jewish observances that are a part of generic Israeli culture).
To outward appearance, one might crudely claim that the Beta-Israel "don't accept the Talmud" however interpreted to mean an overt rejection of Talmud this is simply not so. As evidence of acceptance of the authority of the Talmud one can also readily point to counter-examples of Beta-Israel that are fully halakhically observant, and those that are furthermore enthusiastic members of the rabbinate itself (Rabbi Reuben Wabashat, Rabbi Sharon Shalom, etc.).
If it is the Hakham's claim that their community (or even select members) actively rejects the Talmud (as opposed to your characterization in the comments of "individuals [who] will do what they will just as large swathes of 'Rabbinical Jews' are not orthopraxic") that is something that would require substantiation. Otherwise it is no more than a broad slur against a community that already struggles.

+1. I will note that I once asked an Ethiopian friend who is dati like me (we learned in the same yeshiva in Israel) on the modern Beta Yisrael stance regarding the apocrypha, which at some point was adopted by their community when they were in Ethiopia (a historical reason might be because at some point the church controlled the books that could be used by the Jews). I recall that he mentioned that today there was a minority movement in Israel of youths to return to studying apocryphal texts (Jubilees, Enoch) as a way of returning to what had become traditional in the community.

@Harel13 that is very interesting, thanks for sharing that tidbit  another possible reason for their use of apocrypha could be that their origins may have stemmed from a self-judaized breakaway Christian sect (I say this not has weshalom to cast aspersion on what is definitely today a Jewish community just as a point of historical interpretation of the given facts).
